# Air - Unzipping file

Tags: actionscript-3, air, zip

Currently I am using nochump library for unzipping files. But its very slow(around 30 seconds for 2 mb file). Is there any other libraries available which are fast. Or is thaere any better way to unzip by communicating with os?

I have used FZip, but it wont work in mac. So cant use it.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of... AS3 is quite slow in these areas...

A possible workaround, if you are using zips for loading images, could be using a big JPEG with all of your images inside it (eventually using an aditional XML to determine dimentions, or maybe even custom metadata). Uncompressing images in Flash is quite fast (and asynchronous).

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible using Alchemy (there are very fast Alchemy librairies to encode JPEG and PNG), but I can't find any existing one for unzipping.

Otherwise, you can use the AIR 2.0 beta (not great for production code... depends on your project) to call a native application which will do the job for you.

Anyway, it might get tricky to retrieve progression information if you need it.